# antlr4.7.2, right recursion and ambiguity

Tags: parsing, recursion, antlr4, context-free-grammar, ambiguity

The Antlr 4.7.2 parser made with the following ambiguous, right-recursive context-free grammar fails to parse *fed*:

```
grammar ambrd7;
s : c s | b s | 'd' | 'e' 'd'; // fails on 'fed'
c : 'f' 'e' ;
b : 'f' ;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

The TestRig tool for testing antlr parsers emits an error message: *no viable alternative at input 'fed'*, whereas mathematically this grammar generates *fed* from *s* through several derivations:

```
s --> c s --> 'f' 'e' s --> 'f' 'e' 'd'
s --> b s --> 'f' s --> 'f' 'e' 'd'
```

Does anyone know why the parser fails to parse *fed*?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's really odd. In vscode this grammar works as expected:

[image]

The only idea I have for the failure you see is that you use an outdated test rig.

Comment: I'm running the TestRig of antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar, dated 2018/12/18, in a PowerShell under Windows 10.

Comment: I updated Java to JDK 1.8.0_231 and the symptom is still the same.

Comment: All I can say is that this grammar is ok. Have you tried generating own parser + lexer files and create an application with them to see if that parses correctly?

Comment: Now I realise that for your test you added a rule to the grammar, _start: s;_. An expert's reflex? with this insertion, the parser generated with the new grammar parses _fed_. I don't know why the start symbol _s_ of the original grammar requires this 'protection' (against what?), but I'll remember that antlr 'works better' this way. Thanks, Mike!

Comment: The `start` rule was only added so that I didn't have to change by debug configuration in vscode (which uses the name `start` as entry point). Suprising this did also solve your issue. The only fact that stands out for `s` is that it is recursive. But I don't think that is the reason why the original parsing failed. But maybe there's a bug hidden somewhere? In any case: if my answser helped you to solve your problem then please accept it.